# Pandas with a condition select a value from a column and multiply by scalar in new column, row by row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, if-statement, row, multiplication

A value in 'Target_Labels' is either 0.0,1.0,2.0 in float64.

Based on this value, I would like to look up a value in one of three columns 'B365A','B365D','B365H' and multiply this value by 10 in a new column. This operation needs to be row wise throughout the entire DataFrame.

I have tried many combinations but nothing seem to work...

```
final['amount'] = final['Target_Labels'].apply((lambda x: 'B365A' * 10 if x==0.0 else ('B365D' * 10 if x ==1 else 'B365H' * 10))
 
def prod(x, var1, var2, var3, var4):

    if (x[var4])==0:
         x[var3]*10
    elif (x[var4])==1:
        x[var1]*10
    else:
        x[var2]*10
    return x
final['montant'] = final.apply(lambda x: prod(x, 'B365D', 'B365H','B365A', 'Target_Labels'), axis=1)
```

I'm new to Pandas and any help is welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use numpy to indexing and get individual cells:

- array = `final.values`
- row = `range(len(df))`
- col = `final['Target_Labels'] - 1`

```
>>> final
   B365A  B365D  B365H  Target_Labels
0     11     12     13              1
1     11     12     13              2
2     11     12     13              3

>>> final['amount'] = final.values[(range(len(final)),
                                    final['Target_Labels'] - 1)] * 10

>>> final
   B365A  B365D  B365H  Target_Labels  amount
0     11     12     13              1     110
1     11     12     13              2     120
2     11     12     13              3     130
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. My dataframe is multi index and this is the message I get : 'only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices'
when I try your solution. I will try to remove the multi index (date, item1, item2)

Comment: I fixed my answer. Instead of using `final.index` create a sequence of integers with `range(len(final))`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works ! Don't know how it works in detail but it helps me a lot to keep going with this.

Comment: I was away for a while on vacation and I might have jumped the gun a little on your answer. So essentially, I have to change my target labels to match your scheme for moving around the columns with the indices, row by row? As I cannot have 0,1,2 as my values since 0-1 would take me to the last column...

Comment: ...A value in 'Target_Labels' is either 0.0,1.0,2.0 in float64....